# Small office networking via powerline

Tags: ethernet, congestion

We're moving to a new office that has no cables installed and we're wondering if using a powerline solution would be adequate. It's a small office with 5 users, 1 server, and some additional devices (printers, smartphones, etc...), which total about 10 simultaneous devices connected.

What are the major drawbacks in connecting multiple devices to one powerline adapter, via wi-fi or through cable?

I've used a similar solution at home, with great success, but I'm wondering if having more simultaneous devices connected will create us problems regarding contention ratio or other issues.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason not to use wifi instead?

Comment: @ToddWilcox I'm expecting powerline to be more reliable/faster. Is it a wrong assumption?

Comment: In my experience, powerline solutions are much less reliable in larger and multi-tenancy buildings, especially if they have older electrical. Additionally, they can be much less secure and harder to maintain or troubleshoot. They were really only designed for home use.

Comment: Besides any existing faults with the electrical installation, are there any technical issues using power line?

Comment: I am not talking about just faults, but certain devices will create more "noise" on the electrical system as well. Things like it may work fine until the HVAC system kicks on, and then everything stops working. Or maybe it cuts out whenever your neighbor uses their ancient heavy duty shredder. In today's world, when the network is down then productivity is lost and productivity is measured in $'s. Most business don't like spending money on cabling, but they like lost productivity even less.

Comment: @YLearn, ok that's a insight I wasn't considering. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use powerlines for business network..

Use wifi for what you can, even the usb sticks for the desktops. Place the server near the router and run cable and if you really have to, run long cables, as out-of-the-way as much as you can.

that is the quick solution. eventually run cable properly throughtout the building.

Answer (score 0):

Faster? Maybe. More reliable? My money is on "no." It will, however, be much harder to troubleshoot, and depending on the wiring setup (same phase?, same circuit?) it may not work at all.

In the long run, you're much better off paying someone to string some wires.